# Find patents with classification that have been reexamined

Tags: search, reexamination

The second answer to [this question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/how-does-one-know-if-a-patent-was-reexamined/4899#4899) suggest [patents.google.com](http://patents.google.com) as the best way to search for reexamined patents. However, if I search for the classification 'F25B' and 'reexamination', the results haven't actually been reexamined, they just have the word in the text. Is there a better way to search for reexamined patents by classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[USPTO's PatFT](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm) provides functionality for this. In particular, the re-examination certificate (REEX, where REEX=YES refers to a certificate of re-examination being present) and current CPC classification class (CPCL) are probably be relevant.

The query [REEX/YES and CPCL/F25B](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&p=1&f=S&l=50&Query=REEX%2FYES+and+CPCL%2FF25B&d=PTXT) seems to provide what you want.

Comment: Clicking through some of the patents at that link, APT/2 seems to be _reissue_ rather than _reexamination_, or am I missing something? I can't figure out what other code is reexamination by guessing and checking or googling.

Comment: @ericksonla Absolutely right, I embarrassingly misread the question. I have updated my answer now.